# Error: cannot convert 'CHAR*' {aka 'char*'} to 'const wchar_t*' in VS code

Tags: visual-c++

> note:   initializing argument 1 of 'int wcscmp(const wchar_t*, const
> wchar_t*)'   134 |   int __cdecl wcscmp(const wchar_t *_Str1,const
> wchar_t *_Str2);

I can't figure out why it's throwing this error when trying to build.

```
DWORD GetPidByName(const wchar_t * pName) {
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
    HANDLE snapshot;

    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &pEntry) == TRUE) {
        while (Process32First(snapshot, &pEntry) == TRUE) {
            if (wcscmp(pEntry.szExeFile, pName) == 0) {
                return pEntry.th32ProcessID;
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

The error has to do with converting `wchar_t *`.

Comment: [`PROCESSENTRY32.szExeFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-processentry32) appears to be a `CHAR[]`, not a `const wchar_t*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the ANSI versions (i.e., those which take C-strings as `char`-based) of the `Process32First` function and `PROCESSENTRY32` structure with a `wchar_t` name argument. This won't work.

Either change your `pName` argument to a `const char*` type or, if that is undesirable and/or not possible, then use the 'Unicode' (`wchar_t`-based) versions of the aforementioned function and structure (which have a trailing "W" added to their names), like so:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

DWORD GetPidByName(const wchar_t* pName)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32W pEntry; // Note added trailing "W" - .szExeFile is now wchar_t[]
    HANDLE snapshot;

    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W);

    snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    // Use the function with the added "W" at the end of the name...
    if (Process32FirstW(snapshot, &pEntry) == TRUE) {
        while (Process32FirstW(snapshot, &pEntry) == TRUE) {
            if (wcscmp(pEntry.szExeFile, pName) == 0) {
                return pEntry.th32ProcessID;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0; // Need to return SOMETHING, here, to signal a "not found" result!
}
```

*Note: Unlike many (most) of the WinAPI structures and functions, which are defined as macros that resolve to either an ANSI or Unicode version depending on the build settings (whether or not the `_UNICODE` token is defined), for these Tool Help Library functions/structures, you need to **explicitly** call/use the `wchar_t` versions, if that is desired or required.*

Comment: Great! problem solved i was able to build. Cheers!